# Apache HttpClientBuilder produces ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.config.Lookup

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using `HttpClient` and and I use `httpCore.jar` and still I'm facing an exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.config.Lookup Error
```

around

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

My full code is following

```
package com.rest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class Test33 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ClientProtocolException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=httpClient";

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);


        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        System.out.println("Response Code : "
                        + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The class is available in httpcore 4.4.4.jar, Please check the version of jar and I tried your code and it doesn't throw any class not found exception. If jar is there then please make sure that jar is added to application classpath.